# LCD 16x2 with I2c display blank

Tags: i2c, arduino-esp8266, lcd

I'm trying to display some text on LCD 16x2 through I2C using Wemos D1 Kit with [LiquidCrystal_I2C](https://github.com/johnrickman/LiquidCrystal_I2C) library.
Using code in example folder:

```
//YWROBOT
//Compatible with the Arduino IDE 1.0
//Library version:1.1
#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>

LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x27,16,2);  // set the LCD address to 0x27 for a 16 chars and 2 line display

void setup()
{
  lcd.init();                      // initialize the lcd 
  // Print a message to the LCD.
  lcd.backlight();
  lcd.setCursor(3,0);
  lcd.print("Hello, world!");
  lcd.setCursor(2,1);
  lcd.print("Ywrobot Arduino!");
}
void loop()
{
}
```

But when kit was flashed, LCD display nothing, like this. 
[image: Blank LCD]

I've tried to adjust potentiometer behind but nothing changed. I also tried using I2C Scan to find out I2C adrress, it showed that address is `0x27` same with the code above.

Anyone can help?

--- UPDATE ----

Pin connect:

```
VCC -> 5V
GND -> GND
SDA -> D4 (SDA) / 04
SCL -> D3 (SCL) / 14
```

I've tried altering `lcd.int()` to `lcd.begin(D4, D3)` or `lcd.begin(4,14)` alter to  but it didn't work.

Comment: D1 SCL, D2 SDA?

Comment: no, on Wemos SDA is D4 pin and SCL is D3 pin

Comment: I just have updated some test result on library but it didn't work

Comment: in esp8266 Arduino core all Wemos D1 variants have default pins for Wire library io 4 and io 5. on D1 R2 and mini io 5 is D1 and io 4 is D2. on Wemos D1 R1 io 4 is D14 and io 5 is D15. the  LiquidCrystal_I2C uses Wire.begin() with default pins

Comment: I just have reviewed the pinout. I've realized that you were right. But I wonder that why on board printed ```D14/SDA/D4``` and ```D15/SCL/D3```. What is difference between ```D14``` and ```D4``` or ```D15``` and ```D3```? For now, I cannot check the code if it would work, I will tell you result as soon as possible. Thanks

Comment: sorry, I forgot that the Uno sized Wemos D1 maps io pins to multiple pcb pins so D3 and D4 are same io as D15 and D14 https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/d40dbb458420939bc83e3d9a2cb81a07c4d2d6b8/variants/d1/pins_arduino.h#L38

Comment: hi, I just have figured out problem. After configuring and trying with other lcd and i2c module, it worked perfectly. So, it surely due to i2c module or lcd was broken. Unfortunately, lcd was soldered to i2c, so i cannot check that problem caused by which one. Anyway, i had something can work for my project. Thank for help.

Answer (score 0):

on the back of the lcd you have an blue box, try turning the screw with an screwdriver until you see text. I had the same problem .